# How can I construct a regex that finds all groups between two expressions?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Suppose I have the text

```
lorem ipsum: *(some amount of whitespace)*
data1  *(some amount of whitespace)*
data2 *(some amount of whitespace)*
...dataN *(some amount of whitespace)*
*(empty line)*
```

And I want data1 to dataN.

The regex

```
lorem ipsum: \s*? \n(.+?)\n
```

Will get me data1, but I need more than that.

How would I write a regex to capture an arbitrary number of groups between groups?

Comment: If your question is really about capturing up to a blank line, you could just use [multiline mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M) and capture up to `\n$`.

Comment: I'd like to have the data accessible as individual groups, rather than just one group containing (data1 data2...)

Comment: Why are you using regex for this at all, thinking about it? Why not just `str.splitlines` then you can easily consume all non-blank lines from a line starting `'lorem ipsum'`. *"I'd like to have the data accessible as individual groups"* - it's helpful to mention requirements like that *in the question*.

Comment: That's an excellent point, thanks. Sometimes It's easy to forget about other ways to do things.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it in JavaScript--you should be able to adapt it for Python.

`string.replace(/lorem ipsum:\s*/, "").split(/\s+/);`